# Im trying to update a UISlider with the current time from a AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, sdk, uislider, avplayer, cmtime

I'm trying to update a UISlider with the current time from a AVPlayer.  Im using a NSTimer to call a method with this code every 1 second:

`CMTime duration = audioPlayer.currentTime;
    float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
    NSLog(@"duration: %.2f", seconds);
    nowPlayingSlider.value = seconds;`

The Times being logged right but the uislider never updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the maximumValue property of the UISlider to the duration of the media. It defaults to 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

For a `UISlider`, I always use:

```
[theSlider setValue:value animated:YES];
```

and, it works fine for me. Why do you want a Slider to update the time though? A `UIProgressView` could probably do want you want. Hope that helps!

Comment: This answer doesn't directly answer my question but its a great tip.  I've voted up your answer.  Im using a UISlider so the user can drag it to change the position in the song.

Comment: Ok, make sense. Glad I could be some help.